# Dominican Republic - Transit without visa

Tags: transit, transit-visas, airport-transfer, dominican-republic

According to the Emirates Visa Requirement Tool:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day if the carrier coordinates the transit and takes full responsibility. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

If I have separate tickets OR part of the route is on a single ticket (let's say the part to Dominican Republic but onwards is a separate ticket to Bahamas) under 24 hours (possible overnight), do you think they will allow it?

Also, does Dominican Republic have a eVISA? I checked wikipedia and it has eVISA for Sri Lankan nationals but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: "the carrier coordinates the transit and takes full responsibility" clearly means that they won't accept separate tickets.

Comment: You keep asking about parts of your itinerary from Sri Lanka to the Bahamas. Why don't you ask how to get from there to there visa-free in the first place?

Comment: @Sebastian it’s not usually an easy task, but these days it borders on impossible. OP is trying to be creative, but I’m afraid there are no easy solutions. In normal times I would just recommend getting a transit visa for Canada, the UK and/or Schengen, but this probably takes ages if at all possible at this time...